# AU v3: Ignoring lax activation attempt for unsupported domain: apple-extension-service, viewbridge

Tags: macos, avfoundation, audiounit

There is an [AudioUnitV3Example](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/) sample code by Apple for iOS. As well as **Audio Unit Extension** OS X target template in Xcode (7.2).

I created (for debug purpose) simple [AUv3 PlugIns Host](https://github.com/vgorloff/AUHost) which used AVFoundation API to build playback engine graph. It is working well with standard AudioUnits shipped with OS X. It can **instantiate** AudioUnit, **load preset**, open **effect window**.

But I can't troubleshoot problem with custom AUv3 PlugIn created from **Audio Unit Extension** template.

It was already working some days ago and I was able to hit following breakpoint (as well as reach other code from AudioUnit lifecycle):

```
// AUAudioUnitFactory method.
func createAudioUnitWithComponentDescription(
   desc: AudioComponentDescription) throws -> AUAudioUnit
```

But at some point a faced strange issue. The `completionHandler` for custom PlugIn, from the following method, never gets called:

```
// AVAudioUnit method.
class func instantiateWithComponentDescription(
   audioComponentDescription: AudioComponentDescription,
   options: AudioComponentInstantiationOptions,
   completionHandler: (AVAudioUnit?, NSError?) -> Void)
```

Also there is following log messages in `system.log`:

```
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23653]: debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
     for x86_64.
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23653]: Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
kernel[0]: warning: debugserver(23653) performed out-of-band resume on pid 23652
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23653]: Attach succeeded, ready to debug.
pkd[562]: INSTALLED:ua.com.wavelabs.Attenuator.AttenuatorAU ua.com.wavelabs.Attenuator.AttenuatorAU(1.0.1) <__NSConcreteUUID 0x7f8dcb847fb0> 4FD70868-0F5B-4979-A6DC-4018B4143934 /private/tmp/Attenuator.dst/Applications/Attenuator.app/Contents/PlugIns/AttenuatorAU.appex
pkd[562]: client 23594 plug-in ua.com.wavelabs.Attenuator.AttenuatorAU election := 257
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.MediaLibraryService.23655): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.iTunesLibraryService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.MediaLibraryService.xpc
 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
com.apple.SecurityServer[88]: Session 101187 created
com.apple.SecurityServer[88]: Session 101188 created
com.apple.SecurityServer[88]: Killing auth hosts
com.apple.SecurityServer[88]: Session 101182 destroyed
com.apple.SecurityServer[88]: Session 101189 created
pkd[562]: enabling pid=23652 for plug-in ua.com.wavelabs.Attenuator.AttenuatorAU(1.0.1) 4FD70868-0F5B-4979-A6DC-4018B4143934 /private/tmp/Attenuator.dst/Applications/Attenuator.app/Contents/PlugIns/AttenuatorAU.appex
taskgated-helper[23666]: Starting taskgated-helper
taskgated-helper[23666]: validated embedded provisioning profile: file:///private/tmp/Attenuator.dst/Applications/Attenuator.app/Contents/PlugIns/AttenuatorAU.appex/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile
taskgated-helper[23666]: Found 1 provisioning profiles
taskgated-helper[23666]: allowing entitlement(s) for pid=23665 due to provisioning profile
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23668]: debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
     for x86_64.
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23668]: Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
kernel[0]: warning: debugserver(23668) performed out-of-band resume on pid 23665
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23668]: Attach succeeded, ready to debug.
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.AUHost.23652): Ignoring lax activation attempt for unsupported domain: ua.com.wavelabs.Attenuator.AttenuatorAU.apple-extension-service
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.AUHost.23652): Ignoring lax activation attempt for unsupported domain: ua.com.wavelabs.Attenuator.AttenuatorAU.viewbridge
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.AUHost.23652): Ignoring lax activation attempt for unsupported domain: ua.com.wavelabs.Attenuator.AttenuatorAU
```

From this log we can see that:

- App Extension (PlugIn) successfully registered (`INSTALLED:ua.com.wavelabs.Attenuator.AttenuatorAU`).
- Provisioning file validated and thus no Sandbox related issues (`allowing entitlement(s) for pid=23665 due to provisioning profile`).
- Xcode debugger successfully attached to AUv3 `Host` and Attenuator `App Extension`.

Unfortunately something went wrong after log messages `Ignoring lax activation attempt for unsupported domain ...`. PlugIn load stuck on waiting for return from callback, which will never be triggered.(

---

After stopping Xcode debug there is another part of `system.log`:

```
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23653]: Got a 'k' packet, killing the inferior process.
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23653]: Sending ptrace PT_KILL to terminate inferior process.
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23653]: 1 +0.000000 sec [5c65/0307]: error: ::ptrace (request = PT_THUPDATE, pid = 0x5c64, tid = 0x1903, signal = 0) err = Resource busy (0x00000010)
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23653]: 2 +0.000143 sec [5c65/0307]: error: ::task_info ( target_task = 0x1403, flavor = TASK_BASIC_INFO, task_info_out => 0x7fff56ac9f30, task_info_outCnt => 10 ) err = (os/kern) invalid argument (0x00000004)
com.apple.security.pboxd[23660]: __45-[NSRemoteServiceConnection _setupConnection]_block_invoke_2: connection failed unexpectedly; terminating process; delegate was (
        0   RemoteViewServices                  0x00007fff87e25a28 -[NSRemoteServiceConnection setDelegate:] + 255
        1   com.apple.security.pboxd            0x00000001068e4771 com.apple.security.pboxd + 22385
        2   com.apple.security.pboxd            0x00000001068e4c33 com.apple.security.pboxd + 23603
        3   com.apple.security.pboxd            0x00000001068e3b8d com.apple.security.pboxd + 19341
        4   libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff932b9396 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 35
        5   libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff932b900f _xpc_connection_mach_event + 2198
        6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff914204ca _dispatch_client_callout4 + 9
        7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff9142093c _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 555
        8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff9141d134 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1207
        9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff9141f293 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 735
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff9141833f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff9141c1cf _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff9141ba34 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
        13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8ff3d68f _pthread_wqthread + 1129
        14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8ff3b365 start_wqthread + 13
    )
AttenuatorAU[23665]: host connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x618000300990> connection from pid 23652 invalidated
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23653]: Waited 10 ms for process to be reaped (state = Exited)
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23653]: 3 +0.011781 sec [5c65/1303]: error: ::read ( 3, 0x700000080a40, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23653]: Exiting.
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23668]: 1 +0.000000 sec [5c74/0307]: error: ::task_info ( target_task = 0x1403, flavor = TASK_BASIC_INFO, task_info_out => 0x7fff5c5c2a30, task_info_outCnt => 10 ) err = (os/kern) invalid argument (0x00000004)
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23668]: 2 +0.004318 sec [5c74/1303]: error: ::read ( 3, 0x700000080a40, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.4.120
    [23668]: Exiting.
Xcode[23287]:  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-10119.9/DVTFoundation/Devices/DVTLocalComputer.m:375
    Details:  Error un-registering Plugin: '/tmp/Attenuator.dst/Applications/Attenuator.app/Contents/PlugIns/AttenuatorAU.appex' Error: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=9 "no plugin at /private/tmp/Attenuator.dst/Applications/Attenuator.app/Contents/PlugIns/AttenuatorAU.appex" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=no plugin at /private/tmp/Attenuator.dst/Applications/Attenuator.app/Contents/PlugIns/AttenuatorAU.appex}
    Object:   <DVTLocalComputer: 0x7fd9b9efa050>
    Method:   -stopDebuggingXPCServices:forPairedDevice:
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd9c211cb60>{number = 47, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
pkd[562]: UNINSTALLED:ua.com.wavelabs.Attenuator.AttenuatorAU ua.com.wavelabs.Attenuator.AttenuatorAU(1.0.1) 4FD70868-0F5B-4979-A6DC-4018B4143934 /private/tmp/Attenuator.dst/Applications/Attenuator.app/Contents/PlugIns/AttenuatorAU.appex
```

From this part of log we can see the following:

- Debug terminated.
- App Extension (PlugIn) uninstalled.
- There is also backtrace related `NSRemoteServiceConnection` class.

---

Can anybody explain what are the messages `Ignoring lax activation attempt for ...` about?

Thank you!

---

**Note**: AUv3 `Host` is not a Containing app. Containing app exists as well, but is does nothing except of participating `App Extension` registration.

In order to reproduce issue you can download [source code](https://github.com/vgorloff/AUHost), open project `AUSamplePlugIn/Attenuator.xcodeproj` and launch schema `AttenuatorAU`.

Comment: Found a problem. It was in playback engine threading model.

Comment: `AUv3 Host` application was using `semaphore` on main thread in order to synchronize internal state with plugin load completion handler. But main thread also used by XPC communication between `AUv3 Host` and `PlugIn`. So, it is `deadlock`. In order to solve issue I wrapped `PlugIn` initialization code with dispatch_async call on separate queue. **btw** messages like `Ignoring lax activation attempt for unsupported domain ...` – is not related to initial issue. It is something other. Thanks!